# How to query a parent table and inherited child table together in one query

Tags: postgresql, api, go

I am using go and pq to interface with my postgres database.

I have a simple user table which has basic fields. Id, name, type. My auxillary table, admin inherits from user and adds it's own field `panel`, and another one that is owner and adds `owner`. Whether that be using table inheritance, or a supporting table.

My question is if I hit and endpoint that points to `user/1` at this point I don't know what type of user this person is yet here. I know we can use jwts and other ways to provide this from the front end. I'm more curious about if there is a way to figure out the user and it's type and query the additional fields in one query?

Ie. I hit the endpoint I would Select from users, get the type, then use that type to get the additional fields. So I would effectively be doing two queries on two tables to get the complete data. Is there a better solution of doing this? Is there some optimizations I could do.

Comment: Could you provide a more clear example of your schema, please?

Comment: You can get the information which type it is with a single query. But it's not possible to include all columns from all descendant tables with that query. To get the other columns, you need to query the other tables.